# Blender v2.91 2D Cursor Snaps

Tags: uv

Per title on v2.91 .. is it broken still (in UV Editor)? I tried v2.81 and it also does not snap to vertex. It's also not listed in UV Editors Pivot Point list for unknown reasons. I do see it in Snapping but again .. it doesn't work. The whole concept of a 2D and 3D cursor is rather backwards. I came from Anvil 2D, AutoCad, and Rhino. In AutoCad it's so easy and direct to align one object (be it a 3D solid, a mesh, or some planer geometry) with another object. With mbuttonpan set, middle click becomes a snap menu. So .. select Move command and pick your object .. middle click and pick a snap point for object origin (say an end point) ... go to target object (it can be a coordinate as well), middle click and pick end point .. hit Enter. Done! .. and without perplexing offsets and no ridiculous Closest (which should NOT be default, vertex should be) when you've already defined Origin and Destination points. A variation of that lets you do 3D alignment .. easily. Blender is great at the organic mesh generation and shaping but lousy at some procedural functions. Not sure if 3DS follows the same paradigm as Acad but likely does. So I'm asking if it does work and maybe I don't have something set right?

Comment: Hello :). No, it still doesn't work.  2D cursor snapping options are still underdeveloped as of Blender 2.91. Improvements have been suggested [here on devtalk](https://developer.blender.org/T78391) and here on [Rightclickselect](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/vjdbbc/)

Comment: Thanks. It does work when moving vertexes around but ya .. not with 2D cursor which means that if the cursor isn't exactly centered on the vertex of interest, you will have offsets. Yes .. there is Cursor to selected which is yet another unnecessary step but I guess is the only way ATM to get vertex-cursor centered in UV Editor. No CAD package that I'm aware of nor does Rhino and likely other modeling software use these silly 2D and 3D cursors.